# How to identity if a document matches a template

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Are there any libraries/cloud services out there that can take two documents and tell you if they appear to be of the same type/format. So for example, if I upload two invoice PDFs/images, it would be able to tell me (potentially with a confidence score) if those two documents are of the same type or very similar. I'm assuming some form of machine learning or other type of AI would need to be leveraged, but not 100% sure if there's a solution out there that would do that type of document matching out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is such a specific thing - maybe. In case there isnt:

Try [Tesseract](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php).
And compare texts for similarity.